# Is there a way to auto increment a column with respect to the foreign key in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, auto-increment, db2-luw, surrogate-key

Say I have an address table with the addresses of different facilities of a manufacturing company. 
The foreign key lets me know which company the addresses belong to, but i need a surrogate id to differentiate between each facility. This id should increment automatically based on the foreign key value.
Note : I just need simple integer values for keys.

eg:

My table has the following columns, ORGANIZATION_ID is the foreign key. 
FACILITY_ID is a second surrogate key dependednt on the foreign key.

```
     ADDRESS_TABLE
    ->ORGANIZATION_ID
    ->FACILITY_ID
    ->ADDRESS_LINE_1
    ->ADDRESS_LINE_2
    ->CITY
    ->STATE
    ->ZIP_CODE
```

I want the facility id to increase automatically from 1 depending on the 
    organization id. i.e

```
    ORGANIZATION_ID 1
    FACILITY_ID 1
```

When I insert data for new organization, facility should start from 1

```
    ORGANIZATION_ID 2
    FACILITY_ID 1
```

Next time I insert data for the same organization, my facility id should increment accordingly -

```
    ORGANIZATION_ID 1
    FACILITY_ID 2
```

Is there any way to make this happen in DB2? 
I'm currently on DB2 V 10.5.6

Comment: @Esperento57 I've updated my question again. I've been posting this in between my tight schedule..sorry for the errors..

Comment: why want you do it? Just create a column autoincrement on you table ADDRESS_TABLE as primary key, you should have primary key on all your tables. Its enought for unicity and integrity

Answer (score 2):

No.  Auto-increment, or Identity keys as DB2 calls them, don't support composite keys.

Best you could do would be to have a on insert trigger that handled assigning the values you want.  Possibly making use of a [SEQUENCE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004201.html?pos=2); though you'd have to create a new sequence to use for the facilities of each new organization.